# Error: Bad state : field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Exception caught by widgets library

The following StateError was thrown building FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>#b2b6c):
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> file:///E:/Project/your_store/lib/tabs/home_tab.dart:15:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:86:7)
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:104:41)
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:120:26)
#3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
#4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/product_cart.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference _productRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _productRef.get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }

              // Collection Data ready to display
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                //Display data in List View
                return ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 108.0,
                    bottom: 12.0,
                  ),
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                    return ProductCart(
                      title: document["name"],
                      imageUrl: document["images"[0]],
                      price: "\₹${document["price"]}",
                      productId: document.id,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }

              // Loading State
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          CustomActionBar(
            title: "Home",
            hasBackArrow: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "document.data()" and then try to get the value by accessing the key
e.g:

```
children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
  // final Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data; // <== get the data of the document
  // Edit:
  final dynamic data = document.data();
  return ProductCart(
  title: data["name"],
  imageUrl: data["images"[0]],
  price: "\₹${data["price"]}",
  productId: document.id,
 );
}).toList(),
```

UPD:
Full example:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/product_cart.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference _productRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _productRef.get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }

              // Collection Data ready to display
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                //Display data in List View
                return ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 108.0,
                    bottom: 12.0,
                  ),
                  children:
                      snapshot.data!.docs.map((QueryDocumentSnapshot document) {
                    // Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data();
                    final dynamic data = document.data();

                    return ProductCart(
                      title: data["name"],
                      imageUrl: data["images"[0]],
                      price: "₹${data["price"]}",
                      productId: document.id,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }

              // Loading State
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          CustomActionBar(
            title: "Home",
            hasBackArrow: false,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's giving an error i.e 
A value of type 'Object? Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Comment: Try to change that line to: final dynamic data = document.data();

Comment: The value of local variable 'data' isn't used.

Comment: Replace document with data. But remember to get the id from document, so keep document.id in productId. Get the copy of the code above if you didn't already.

Comment: Actually, I'm just a beginner so I'm not much familiar with all these so it would be a great help if you could give me an example by implementing this in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235105/discussion-between-bhaskar2510-and-maksim-nikolaev).